# Pandas Dataframe Checking Consecutive Values in a colum

Tags: pandas

Have a Pandas Dataframe like below.

```
EventOccurrence Month
1                4
1                5
1                6
1                9
1                10
1                12
```

Need to add a identifier column to above panda's dataframe such that whenever Month is consecutive thrice a value of True is filled, else false. Explored few options like shift and window without luck. Any pointer is appreciated.

```
EventOccurrence Month Flag
1               4       F  
1               5       F
1               6       T
1               9       F
1               10      F
1               12      F
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the `diff` between rows is one, and the `diff` shifted by 1 is one as well:

```
df['Flag'] = (df.Month.diff() == 1) & (df.Month.diff().shift() == 1)

   EventOccurrence  Month   Flag
0                1      4  False
1                1      5  False
2                1      6   True
3                1      9  False
4                1     10  False
5                1     12  False
```

Note that this will also return True if it is consecutive > 3 times, but that behaviour wasn't specified in the question so I'll assume it's OK

If it needs to *only* flag the third one, and not for example the fourth consecutive instance, you could add a condition:

```
df['Flag'] = (df.Month.diff() == 1) & (df.Month.diff().shift() == 1) & (df.Month.diff().shift(2) !=1)
```

Comment: superb...Thanks for your time..a crisp and correct answer. Appreciate your help.